# How do I force reboot my phone when the lock/side key is broken?

Tags: samsung, boot-loop, lineageos, reboot

is there anyway for me to force reboot my phone when the lock/side key is broken? Well the situation here is:

- I flashed a module
- It made SystemUI broken
- I wanted to force reboot but the side key was broken
- Now the phone is stuck on black screen but remains MTP mode on.

Well this is what I am trying so far:

- Tried ADB command, eg. adb reboot recovery
- Doing MTP tricks for Samsung phones
- Holding 2 volume keys
- Accessing phone data (On windows, it is not showing, on Ubuntu, mount failure)

About my phone:

Samsung Galaxy A30
System/ROM: Lineage 20 (Nov 2023 Security Patch)